# Let $f(x) =7x^{32}+5x^{22}+3x^{12}+x^2$. Then find its remainder in the following cases.

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x) =7x^{32}+5x^{22}+3x^{12}+x^2$.

**(i)** Then find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $[x^2+1]$.

**(ii)** Also find the remainder when $xf(x)$ is divided by $[x^2+1]$.

Given both the remainders will be of the form $4(ax+b)$.

The **'polynomial long division method'** can be applied, but that won't be logical enough, because its too long a process.

Can you tell me any other shorter & easier process?

Thanks.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation, space after period, and no space before.

Comment: What does "not logical enough" mean?

Comment: @salmonkiller it means that OP will have to do 16 'steps' of long division, which _is_ long for a problem.

Comment: A broad hint: what is $x^2$ equivalent to $\pmod {x^2+1}$?

Comment: @salmonkiller If i use long division it would be too long a process,i think.So i'm searching for a better process & want help.

Comment: @Gregory Grant: Ok sir.

Comment: To whoever down-voted this question: There seem to be a couple of good answers below, making this question "well in place". OP asked if there was a solution "more neat" than the obvious long-division, and it turns out that there is. Just cause you don't see a point in the question, doesn't mean you have to go around down-voting it. Please keep your down-votes to when they are actually justified!!!

Comment: I didn't vote it down, I voted it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first case, note that only even powers of $x$ are involved, so you can substitute $y=x^2$. In this case you should find the remainder of $7y^{16}+5y^{11} + 3y^6 + y$ divided by $y+1$, i.e.
$$7(-1)^{16}+5(-1)^{11} + 3(-1)^6 + (-1) = 4$$

So you have $f(x) = q(x)(x^2+1)+4$, where $q(x)$ is some polynomial.

From this follows that $xf(x) = xq(x)(x^2+1) +4x$, so the second remainder is $4x$.

Comment: Good answer! In this case one definitely doesn't need to appeal to the machinery I did in my answer :).

Answer (score 2):

**(i)** Note that $f(i)=7-5+3-1=4$, so the remainder is $4$.

**(ii)** Note that $if(i)=7i-5i+3i-i=4i$, so the remainder is $4x$.

This method uses the isomorphism $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+1)}\simeq\mathbb{Z}[i]$, with $\varphi(x)=i$.

Comment: Can you please expand and maybe mention the method?

Comment: Why did you choose $x=i$ and not any other (real or complex) value?

Comment: @barakmanos I think that Peter Woolfitt used the isomorphism $R[x]/(x^2+1) = R[i] = C$. This is a little abstract approach, for people who is not comfortable with complex numbers.

Comment: @Crostul: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @barakmanos I did as Crostul suggested, and have updated my post.

Comment: @barakmanos The isomorphism is $\varphi(x)=i$, which is why I used $i$ as opposed to other numbers.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\,\ x^2\!+1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, f(\color{#c00}{x^2})\equiv f(\color{#c00}{-1}),\ $ $\,xf(\color{#c00}{x^2})\equiv xf(\color{#c00}{-1}),\ $ for $\ f\in\Bbb Z[x]$